How to find the vuestic admin's sidebar icons?
i expect who can teach i use this icon,or teach me how to find the icons, i really can't do that
And i control+shift+f search and see this ,don't find where are the icons from
enter image description here
this is the image
enter image description here

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

i have solve it,just use https://fonts.google.com/icons icon,find the name can work
